# Grouping by Session ID in BigQuery for GA4 data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm currently trying to build a query that allows me to group all my GA4 event data by session ID in order to get information about the all the events, per session, as opposed to analyzing the data by each event separately.

The resulting output of my initial query is a new table that has session ID as its own column in the table, instead of being within an array for event parameters for a particular event.

The problem is that the session_id column has non-unique values, a session id is repeated multiple times for each row that is a new event (that happens within that session). I am trying to combine (merge) those non-unique session ids so that I can get ALL the events associated with a particular session_id.

I have tried this query which provides me with session_id as a new column, that is repeated for each event.

```
`SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT COALESCE(value.int_value, value.float_value, value.double_value)
    FROM UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE key = 'ga_session_id'
  ) AS session_id,
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(value.string_value)
    FROM UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE key = 'page_location'
  ) AS page_location
FROM
  `digital-marketing-xxxxxx.analytics_xxxxxxx.events_intraday*``
```

gives me an output like (it has way more columns than this but just an example):

| session_id | event_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | session_start |
| 1234567 | click_url |

I need a way to basically merge the two session ids into a single cell. When I try this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT COALESCE(value.int_value, value.float_value, value.double_value)
    FROM UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE key = 'ga_session_id'
  ) AS session_id,
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(value.string_value)
    FROM UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE key = 'page_location'
  ) AS page_location
FROM
  `digital-marketing-xxxxxxx.analytics_xxxxxxx.events_intraday*`
GROUP BY session_id
```

I get an error that tells me (if I understand correctly) that I can't aggregate certain values (like date) which is what the code is trying to do when attempting to group by session id.

Is there any way around this? I'm new to SQL but the searches I've done do far haven't given me a clear answer on how to attempt this.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to understand sequence of events, it might not be that efficient as I have it set up to look at other things as well

```
with _latest as (
  SELECT 
    --create unique id
            concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')) as unique_session_id,
    
    --create event id
        concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id'),event_name) as session_ids,
          event_name,
          event_date,
           
          TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS event_timestamp
        FROM  *******
       
        where
            -- change the date range by using static and/or dynamic dates
           _table_suffix between  '20221113' and '20221114'),
     Exit_count as (
        select *,
     row_number() over (partition by session_ids order by event_timestamp desc) as Event_order
        from _latest)
    
        select 
    Event_order,
    unique_session_id,
        event_date,
        event_name,
        
   FROM
        Exit_count
    
  group by
        Event_order,
        event_name,
        unique_session_id,
        --pagepath,
        event_date
        --Country_site
        order by
            unique_session_id, 
            Event_order
```

Comment: Hey Max_Stone! Thanks for your reply. I tried this code and it's a good solution to get info about only the events, barring the event params. I actually ended up finding a different solution (still working on top of it a bit and will reply back here when I've finalized the code), I followed this tutorial online if you're curious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xiy3xaFZGw&list=PLGXZC1nQpK7cRjJn15ksQZLd3BJ_5CYq9